# Comunicar componentes en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, component

Estoy empezando con React y estoy intentando hacer un conversor de monedas muy sencillo. En el primer componente tengo una lista de las monedas y creo 2 selects para seleccionar las monedas que se quieren convertir y el segundo en cual se va a convertir.

Mi problema es que necesito que el segundo componente pueda acceder a las variables del primero para saber que monedas se han seleccionado. Se que se muestra en el primero tambien, es solo por saber como hacerlo.

Primer componente:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const Moneda1Component = () => {

  const monedas = [
    "-",
    "Euro",
    "Dolar",
    "Yen"
  ]
  

  let [moneda1, setMoneda1] = useState("");
  let [moneda2, setMoneda2] = useState("");

  const cambiarMoneda1 = (nuevaMoneda1) =>{
    setMoneda1(nuevaMoneda1);
  }
  const cambiarMoneda2 = (nuevaMoneda2) =>{
    setMoneda2(nuevaMoneda2);
  }

  return (
    <div className='d-flex justify-content-around'>
    <div className='row-4'>
      <h4 className='mt-4'>Seleccione la moneda de origen</h4>
      <br/>
        <select>
            {
              monedas.map( (moneda, indice) =>{
                return(<option value={moneda} key={indice} onClick={e => cambiarMoneda1(e.target.value)}>
                  {moneda}
                </option>);
              })
            }
        </select>
        {(moneda1 !=="" && moneda1 !== "-") ? <p className='mt-2'>Moneda de origen: {moneda1}</p> : null}
    </div>
    <div className='row-4'>
      <h4 className='mt-4'>Seleccione la moneda de destino</h4>
      <br/>
        <select>
            {
              monedas.map( (moneda, indice) =>{
                if(moneda===moneda1){
                  return(false);
                }
                return(<option value={moneda} key={indice} onClick={e => cambiarMoneda2(e.target.value)}>
                  {moneda}
                </option>);
              })
            }
        </select>
        {(moneda2 !=="" && moneda2 !== "-") ? <p className='mt-2'>Moneda de destino: {moneda2}</p> : null}
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Segundo componente:

```
import React from 'react'

export const CantidadConvertir = () => {

  return (
    <div>
        <p>La moneda de origen es: </p>
        <p>La moneda de destino es: </p>
        //Aqui va en input para introducir la cantidad a convertir.
    </div>
  )
}
```

PD: Seguramente haya mucho disparate por ahí escrito, tened paciencia con un novato xD

Comment: Dónde estás renderizando los dos componentes? qué posición tienen en tu árbol de componentes? si renderizas uno dentro del otro puedes fácilmente mandarlo por props, pero si no, probablemente lo mejor es que uses redux

Comment: Al final acabé renderizando uno dentro y lo hice con props. No era lo que tenía en mente pero no tenía muy claro como hacerlo de otra manera. Le echaré un vistazo a Redux, gracias!

Comment: También puedes usar `useContext` para pasar automaticamente propiedades comunes a ambos componentes (Info aqui: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)